# Can users in a group access a file that is in another user's home directory?

Tags: permissions, security, git, group, access-control

I have 3 users **A**,**B** and **C** inside a group 'admin'. I have another user '**D**' in whose home directory, there is a `project` folder. I have made **D** as the owner of that folder and assigned 'admin' as the group using `chgrp`. Group and owners have all the permissions, but still **A**,**B** or **C** are unable to access the folder. I have two question :

1. Is it even possible for other users to access anything in another user's directory
2. Giving rights to a group only makes the users in that group have access to files that are outside any user's home directory ?

**Edit** : Here is how I had set the owner and group of the project

```
sudo chown -R D project
sudo chgrp -R admin project
```

I got an error while trying to get into the `project` folder within **D**'s home directory (while being logged in as **A**)

```
cd /home/D/project
-bash: cd: /home/D/project: Permission denied
```

Here is the output of `ls -la` command :

```
drwxrwsr-x 7 D admin      4096 Nov 18 13:06 project
```

Here is the description of the group `admin` :

```
getent group admin
admin_users:x:501:A,B,C
```

Also note that group `admin` is not being listed when I type `groups` from the user **D**, but was visible when I used `cut -d: -f1 /etc/group`. The user I am referring to as **D** is actually `ec2-user`(the default Fedora user on Amazon servers)

Ultimately, I'm setting up a git repository on a server. I have created the repo in **D**'s home directory, but wish **A**, **B** and **C** to have access to it too (and clone them)

Comment: Nice.  Much bigger picture now.  Do ABC need to update, or only clone? Will ABC (and D) be logged in to the server, or accessing remotely (via,http,git,ssh?)  Do you have root permissions on the server?  `Git` has some internal settings that help enable this situation.

Comment: A,B,C can update the repository and they will be accessing it remotely. I have root access on the server.

Comment: Gave both answers +1, and you get +1 also for anticipating I would have this *exact same question* nearly 10 years later :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some points that seem to be necessary (though I freely admit that I am not expert in these matters), and that were not covered in RobertL's otherwise admirably thorough answer.

1. Make sure that the other users have actually logged into group `admin`:

> `A$ newgrp admin`

Since the users are already in the group, I think you will **not** need to set a group password. If you do:

> `A$ sudo chgpasswd`
>   `admin:secret`   (typed into stdin)

2. Make sure that **D**'s home directory is in group `admin` and is group-searchable.

> `D$ chgrp admin ~`
>   `D$ chmod g+x ~`
>   `D$ ls -lad ~`
>   `drwx--x--- 3 D admin 4096 Nov 24 19:25 /home/D`

The directory needs to be searchable to allow users to enter it or its subdirectory `project`. It doesn't need to be group-**readable**, so **D**'s own filenames are still private. To let the other users get to `project` easily, have them create symbolic links to it; otherwise, they'll have to type the whole path each time (autocomplete won't work because the shell can't read the pathname, it can only go to it).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your point 2 did the trick! (logging into the group wasn't required though)

Comment: Yes! Easy to see why this is the accepted answer - Robert's answer was great also, but your # 2 is what made his answer actually work. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 12):

1. Yes it is possible for users to access files in another users home directory.
2. No, there is no special treatment of home directories outside the system file permissions. "*Giving rights to a group*" involves two parts, granting group ownership, and setting group permissions. Your example deals only with ownership.

You can set *permissions* recursively with the `chmod` command but that alone may not guarantee that new files created by one member of the group will be accessible to the others.

Thank you for the account of what you've done so far, with adequate details, and for stating your goal to share `git` repositories.

Let's first look at how to accomplish group file sharing on Unix and Linux in a general way, and then look at some considerations for `git`.

## Basic Group File Sharing Configuration

Here are some basics of this type of file sharing in Unix and GNU, etc. This is a simple way to set up a one or more directories where all members of a group have read and write permissions on files created by other users in the group.

Let's assume your common user group will be `gitusers` and the directory is `repo`.

1. Put sharing members into a common group (for example `gitusers`).
2. Set `umask 002` for all of the users in the group, indicating that most files will be created group-writable by default. This may be set in various shell startup files (such as `/etc/bash.bashrc`). On GNU/Linux systems see `man 8 pam_umask` and `man umask` for more and better information.
3. Set group ownership recursively (`-R`) on all shared files:

   ```
   chgrp -R gitusers repo
   ```
4. Set group read and write permissions recursively on all files:

   ```
   chmod -R g+rw repo
   ```
5. Set the `set group id on execution bit` (`setgid`) of repo and all subdirectories. The `setgid` indicates that newly created files and subdirectories in that directory inherit the same group ownership as the parent directory. New subdirectories also have the `setgid` bit set, for a recursive effect:

   ```
   find repo -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
   ```

After the above steps, you should be well on your way for all users in the same group `gitusers` in the example, to read and write each other's files, while disallowing write permission for users not in the `gitusers` sharing group. You can replicate the `chown`, `chmod` and `find` command on as many directories as you wish, for any sharing purpose you wish, not just `git`.

## Sharing `git` Repositories

It appears that `git` may work OK with only the above configuration changes.  However `git` also knows about sharing and group permissions (and may actually do some of the above for you).

If you're creating a shared `git` repository, consider these options:

```
git init --bare --shared=group  repo
```

If you have an existing repository, consider these settings:

1. core.bare
2. core.sharedRepository=group

See the [`git-init` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html) and [the `git-config` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for more details.

## Notes

While a bare, group-shared `git` repository will take care of some of the same steps as in the general example, I would recommend performing the steps in the general example as well to ensure consistency and also ease in setting up any other shared directories.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have added some more information. Please tell me if you need any more

Comment: I further added the group info and a new second last para

Comment: @Daud, did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Yes. As suggested by Tom below, I had to make *D*'s home directory searchable for the group *AND* change the group of *D*'s home directory to *admin*. Thanks a lot for such a thorough answer. I just wish I could mark both answers as **accepted**

Comment: A very good answer! +1